# Switch off Validations during ajax call

Tags: jsf, validation

I have a JSF page in which I am iterating a list to display the `<h:dataTable>` with some rows containing checkbox, some text and a textbox. I have added validations such that if a chechbox in a row is checked, the user must enter value inside the corresponding textbox. Also, I have a checkbox with id 'copy' above the `<h:dataTable>` which should copy the value entered in the first textbox to all other textboxes whose checkboxes are checked within the `<h:dataTable>`.I used an ajax call for the same.

```
 <h:form prependId="false" id="form">
 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.copy}" id="copy">
        <p:ajax process="#{bean.mailId}"
            event="change" partialSubmit="true" 
            listener="#{Controller.copyEmail()}"
            update="rm">
        </p:ajax>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

   <h:dataTable id="rm" width="100%" cellspacing="4"
        value="#{controller.alertTriggers}" var="alt"
            columnClasses="c1,c2,c3,c4">  
            <h:column>
                  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{alt.checkValue}" id="checkbox" binding="#{checkbox}"/>
               </h:column>
                <h:column>
                   <h:outputText value="#{alt.id}" />                                       
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                  <h:outputFormat value="#{alt.msg1}" />                              
                </h:column>
                <h:column>                                              
                     <h:message for="emailID" id="email" styleClass="validation-error"/>
                     <h:inputText value="#{alt.mailId}" id="emailID" style="width: 87%;" required="#{checkbox.value}" requiredMessage="Enter the value"/>

                </h:column>                                         

  </h:dataTable>                                          
 </h:form>
```

In the controller

```
public void copyEmail() {

//code for copying the first textbox value to all other textboxes

}
```

The Validation works fine, but when i check the **copy** checkbox, the textbox value do not get copied to the other textboxes. Instead, validation errors are shown. If I remove validations from the textbox, the copying part works fine.

I tried using `immediate=true` for my ajax call but then the value of the checkboxes inside the `<h:dataTable>` are not updated within the controller.

So, in summary

**I want to switch off my validations during the ajax call. Is there any way to do that other than `immediate=true`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you want to validate the input text field as `required` only when the checkbox is checked **and** the true save button is pressed? If so, then you'd need to extend the `required` attribute with another check if the save button is been pressed. You can check that by the presence of the save button's client ID in the request parameter map.

E.g.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{checkbox}" .../>
...
<h:inputText ... required="#{checkbox.value and not empty param[save.clientId]}" />
...
<p:commandButton binding="#{save}" ... />
```